# How to merge detached head, into new branch and then new branch to be master?

Tags: git, github

When I type git branch I get this.

```
* (HEAD detached from 731c587)
  addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore
  master
```

I want everything on `HEAD detached from 731c587` to be my final code and I suppose the final code of the project should always be on master?

Again, I'm not totally sure how git works, but I think this detached head is from the `addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore` branch. How can I merge the detached head into the `addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore` branch, and then the `addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore` branch into master?

In the end, I want to push this repo to git and have all my latest changes.

Comment: is master (the revision it is currently on) part of the history of the revision that you have on HEAD? In other words.... an ancestor (direct ornindirect) of HEAD?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I was working on master for about 4 months, then created a new branch addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore, then was working off this branch for about 2 months doing many changes to the app, not just what the branch name describes. So I want addNewJobQueueForCandidateProfileStore branch to be my latest code, so I can push this to a repository on Github.

Comment: @RyanSacks you can find that out from your current state with `git branch --merged HEAD`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the information.
I resolved conflicts and then I created a new branch called `my-latest-changes` from the detached head state I was on. After that I creating a Pull request. Then I did `git merge my-latest-changes` from master and everything is good now, I used `git push origin master` to push my latest changes. (I made not have done all of these steps in the exact order, but this is what I did).

Answer (score 1):

Branch refs are labels on commits. Really. If you want a label on that commit, add one. Or don't bother, just merge the history by its tip commit's id instead of some arbitrary invented name, the entire value of a mnemonic ref is threefold: it lets Git know you care about that history at the moment, it lets you associate notes like default command settings, and ... actually that's it. `git commit` updates the `HEAD` ref. When you check out a branch, `git checkout` and its new little cousins turn the `HEAD` ref into a temporary alias for another ref, the branch ref, so Git updates that instead when commands update `HEAD`. That is, literally, all there is to it.